# Problem with Autonomous robot motion: amcl

Tags: navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot has been set up for autonomous motion using amcl & move_base from ROS navigation stack. The robot performs correctly using teleop; and the motors follow the velocity values published by move_base well enough. The problem is that, after defining the path between the robot and the goal position correctly, my robot fails to follow it (the defined path). I have uploaded a video of what the robot's simulation does in rviz here: https://youtu.be/cRTHVMGiG0I

Also, The robot driver subscribes to the rostopic navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel to run the motors (since values are not being published on cmd_vel topic)

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening? (please watch the video in the provided url)

### Here are my move_base parameters:

shutdown_costmaps: false

controller_frequency: 5.0
controller_patience: 3.0

planner_frequency: 1.0
planner_patience: 5.0

oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.8

base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"

base_global_planner: "navfn/NavfnROS" #alternatives:global_planner/GlobalPlanner

### And these are the dwa_planner params:

max_vel_x: 0.5
min_vel_x: 0.0

max_vel_y: 0.0
min_vel_y: 0.0

max_trans_vel: 0.5
min_trans_vel: 0.1
trans_stopped_vel: 0.1

max_rot_vel: 5.0
min_rot_vel: 0.4
rot_stopped_vel: 0.4

acc_lim_x: 0.5
acc_lim_theta: 2.0
acc_lim_y: 0.0

yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15

sim_time: 1.0
vx_samples: 6
vy_samples: 1
vtheta_samples: 20

path_distance_bias: 64.0
goal_distance_bias: 24.0
occdist_scale: 0.5
forward_point_distance: 0.325
stop_time_buffer: 0.2
scaling_speed: 0.25
max_scaling_factor: 0.2

oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

publish_traj_pc : true
publish_cost_grid_pc: true
global_frame_id: odom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233084/problem-with-autonomous-robot-motion:-amcl/) by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-28**:
I can see multiple possible error sources there. (e.g. is this the map for localization? is the robot turning right when you command left? ...) please provide your configurations, maybe a video of Gazebo next to rviz, a bagfile...

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-04-28**:
I have added the configuration parameters for move_base and dwa_local planner in the original question. Please refer to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the problem. The base_frame parameter in move_base node was set to base_link. I changed it to base_footprint. Now the robot follows its path  properly and reaches its goal. Thanks everyone for help.

---

Originally posted by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) with karma: 66 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0